# Error: package databinding does not exist

Tags: data-binding, package, android-databinding, renaming

I renamed packages of a existing android project by refactoring. At the first rebuild it worked fine and after few rebuilds it gives error package `com.shopping.assistant` does not exist.

my `Grandle.build` file `databinding = true` and
I renamed package correctly

Is that a problem in IDE that about updating.?

Comment: Hi! Im facing the same issue all the time. Have you found the root cause of that issue please?